# redis config set fails for slaveof

Tags: redis

I am working with a master slave redis replication setup with redis version 2.4.15-1. I am testing to manually update the setting of one of the slaves to upgrade it to a master once the original master goes down. But from the client, I keep getting the following:

redis server:6381> CONFIG SET SLAVEOF "NO ONE"
(error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: SLAVEOF

Would I necessarily need to restart redis-server to do this? I assumed otherwise based on http://redis.io/topics/admin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SLAVEOF` is a command itself, not a config variable. You can make your server a slave of another server by running this on your slave:

```
SLAVEOF my.host.com 1234
```

(Where `my.host.com` is the server host and `1234` is your server port.)

If your master instance has a password, you'll need to set the `MASTERAUTH` config variable:

```
CONFIG SET MASTERAUTH foobar
```

Comment: What should be the `SLAVEOF` setting for the master; `NO ONE`, or leave it commented out?

Comment: You'll want to set it to "NO ONE" to make a server a master server.